# Update deviceToken of an installation in Parse using ReST API

Tags: android, ios, rest, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using Parse.com for push notifications and I use it extensively through their ReST APIs. My app pushes the device token to my server which then creates an `Installation` entity on Parse.com with that token and an identifier.

Now when the device token changes I am updating the `Installation` entity on Parse.com using the update API (https://parse.com/docs/rest#installations-updating). However I am getting the following error response : `{code: 136, error: "deviceToken may not be changed in this operation"}`

The same question was asked here https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-update-devicetoken-using-cloud-coderest-api 8 months back but no answer has been provided.

Anyone knows how to go about this?